# FATAL: No bootable medium found! System halted

Tags: windows, windows-xp, virtual-machine, virtualbox

downloaded Windows XP SP3 ISO image from Microsoft.com here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25129 and I am using Oracle's VM VirtualBox to create a new VM. I load it using VM and select the media as the 545 MB .iso I just downloaded and I get "FATAL: No bootable medium found! System halted."

Help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That CD only contains the SP3 update.
It is not a full Windows XP installation CD, and it is not bootable.

Comment: Ooooh, I see my mistake. Thank you. Where can I get the actual ISO?

Comment: unless you have the original CD/license, an [MSDN subcription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/buy.aspx), or [windows 7](https://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx/) then it's not legally possible